# Does ClojureBox support auto-align out of the box?

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurebox

I am switching to Clojurebox to edit my clojure files. However I can't get the automatic alignment to work. I want the cursor to move two spaces after the line that I am editing when I hit return.

Answer (score 1):

The key combination for newline-and-indent in Emacs is <kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit TAB when your mark is somewhere in a line, it (clojure-mode) indents the line you are on.
Also you can mark a bunch of code with C-SPC + arrows and hit TAB to indent that.